# How to set a placeholder to a form element in a exposed view filter?

Tags: 8, views

I have an exposed view filter in a view and I need to put one element label as a [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) in his edit form element. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can implement the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` hook, in the case of the view exposed filter form the name is `views_exposed_form`

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  //You need to verify the id
  switch ($form['#id']) {
    case 'views-exposed-form-nouvelles-page-1':
      //Setting placeholder
      $form['title']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $form['#info']['filter-title']['label'];
      //Cleaning the filter labels
      unset($form['#info']['filter-title']['label']);
      break;
  }
}
```

How you can find the element name? It's easy, you can Inspect your Element:

[image]